# Cross import in the same directory

Tags: python, django

I'm using Python 3 with Django and I try to make cross imports which fails and I don't know why...
Here is the structure:

```
|--my_project
   |-- system
     |--__init__.py
     |-- a.py
     |-- b.py
```

*a.py*

```
from .b import TestB
class TestA(object):
    pass
```

*b.py*

```
from .a import TestA
class TestB(object):
    pass
```

The import in a.py works. But the one in b.py doesn't work: `ImportError: cannot import name 'TestA'`. I also tried using absolute path (`from myproject.system.a import TestA` but with no luck).
Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting imports at the end of your a.py and b.py should fix issues. 
If it doesn't help you try to move import into class definition block, so replace

```
from .a import TestA
Class TestB(object):
    pass
```

to

```
Class TestB(object):
    from .a import TestA
    pass
```

**Small Suggestion**: do not use relative imports.

Answer (score 1):

There're several approaches you can use to address the cross-imports problem:

- Re-organize your modules so that there're no cross-imports, i.e. put the classes to a single module, etc.
- Replace `from module import foo` with `import module` and use full names.
- Put imports at the end of modules (not recommended).

See also [Circular imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744373/244297).